# How to add jQuery loop to summarize every input

Tags: jquery, html

I made append function so whoever click `#add` button new input will be added and i want to make loop and summarize all input values

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#square').on('click', '#add', function() {
    var value = $('#addmore').val();
    var html = value + '<input id="inp3" class="number"><br>';
    $('#secondary').append(html);
  })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#secondary").on("click", "#sum", function() {
    // I WANT LOOP HERE
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
  <h1>calculate</h1>
  <div id="secondary">
    Your daily salary: <input id="salary" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"> <input id="addmore"><button id="add">add more</button><br> Your business income daily <input id="income" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"><br>
    <button id="sum">summarise</button>
    <input type="number" class="gl" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly you need to use a class, not an ID - then `$(".inp3").each(function() {...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add value attribute for input.

```
var html = value + '<input id="inp3" class="number" value=' + value +'><br>';
```

And use `each` method to sum

```
var total = 0;
        $('#secondary .number').each(function(index, item){

          total += parseFloat($(item).val());
        })
        console.log(total);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#square').on('click', '#add', function() {
    var value = $('#addmore').val();
    var html = value + '<input id="inp3" class="number" value=' + value +'><br>';
    $('#secondary').append(html);
  })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#secondary").on("click", "#sum", function() {
    // I WANT LOOP HERE
    var total = 0;
        $('#secondary .number').each(function(index, item){
        
          total += parseFloat($(item).val());
        })
        console.log(total);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
  <h1>calculate</h1>
  <div id="secondary">
    Your daily salary: <input id="salary" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"> <input id="addmore"><button id="add">add more</button><br> Your business income daily <input id="income" type="number" class="inp" placeholder="Enter your daily salary"><br>
    <button id="sum">summarise</button>
    <input type="number" class="gl" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `parseFloat(this.value);` or  `parseFloat($(this).val());` no need to re-find the object

Answer (score 0):

If you add a consistent class to all your classes like @mplungjan mentioned, you can then use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop over each of your inputs. Here I have created the class `.pay` and added it to your input elements. You can then use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to convert your the value to a number to ensure you perform addition rather than concatenation.

See example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#square').on('click', '#add', function() {
    var value = $('#addmore').val();
    var html = value + '<input id="inp3" class="pay number"><br>';
    $('#secondary').append(html);
  })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#secondary").on("click", "#sum", function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.pay').each(function() {
      sum += +$(this).val(); // unary plus operator $(this).val(); will convert $(this).val(); to a number   
    });
    $(".gl").val(sum);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="square">
  <h1>calculate</h1>
  <div id="secondary">
    Your daily salary: <input class="pay" id="salary" type="number"  placeholder="Enter your daily salary"> <input id="addmore" class="pay"><button id="add">add more</button><br> Your business income daily <input class="pay" id="income" type="number"  placeholder="Enter your daily salary"><br>
    <button id="sum">summarise</button>
    <input type="number" class="gl" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```